# SQL Server Foreign Key Constraint Error, But Data Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I continue getting an insert error referencing a foreign key constraint error that I can't figure out. The related data is there... so what is causing this error?

Here's the data and insert statement:

[image]

Here are the relationships:

[image]

And here are the details on the foreign key in question:

[image]

The scripting on the table that created the constraint looks good to me:
[image]

Also, through some other research, I've confirmed there are not any transactions left open and also that there are no violating FK values.

*open transaction check: `SELECT er.session_id, er.open_transaction_count FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er Where open_transaction_count > 0`

*violating FK info: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2326/find-violating-sql-server-foreign-key-values/

It may be staring me in the face and I've been staring at it too long now, not sure. But, any new set of eyes and ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Script out the table and see if your foreign keys are mapped properly. That's where I'd start.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Also before you ask & search make a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of the foreign key are mixed up.
DivisionId references permissionRoleId etc. Put the columns in the right order.

Comment: This was created initially by EF Core 2.2 Framework and I read on MS site: "A FOREIGN KEY constraint specified at the table level must have the same number of reference columns as the number of columns in the constraint column list. The data type of each reference column must also be the same as the corresponding column in the column list.".I see the column names in the brackets, so I am under the assumption that the column order didn't matter. But, at this point, it is definitely worth a try. If it works, I'll need to then find out why EF didn't care about that.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the foreign key and re-created it via SMSS. It looks differently than what EF had created, but it is now working. So, this just means this will be transferring the "issue" from SQL to EF. Thank you @lptr!